# SQLite3 Order by list?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQL query where I am taking an arbitrary list of ids that may be in any order that I want to fetch.

```
select * from apps where id in (3,5,1);
```

This works as desired. How can I make a query that also orders the apps by this list, like this (Which doesn't work)? Or do I have to sort these in the rest of my program?

```
select * from apps where id in (3,5,1) order by (3,5,1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement for this:

```
select *
from apps
where id in (3, 5, 1)
order by (case id when 3 then 1
                  when 5 then 2
                  when 1 then 3
          end);
```